# How to implement office location page in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, intranet, geolocation

I need to create office location in SharePoint intranet. I have an idea of using GEO location column as an option with all other fields and displaying it with filter web part.
Is there any better solution to suggest. would really appreciate ideas on designing location page for intranet in SharePoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

take the Google map snippet and put it in a script editor. Total time spent= 13 seconds